# Optimizer not using declared partials?

Tags: openmdao

I am using OpenMDAO to drive a CFD optimization.  The computational geometry, meshing, and solver execution is handled by a separate python script which takes in the updated design.  In one execution, the script will solve for the forces, but also the derivatives through an adjoint analysis.  My issue is that OpenMDAO only seems to be using the derivatives, which I have specified, part of the time and not for every iteration.  Below is a sample of the code that I am using:

```py
import os
import argparse
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv
import f90nml
import socket
import sys
import pickle

# Import OpenMDAO module - currently tested against version 2.8.0
from openmdao.api import Problem, Group, IndepVarComp, ExplicitComponent, ScipyOptimizeDriver
import openmdao.api as om

class FUN3DExternalCodeComp(om.ExternalCodeComp):

    def setup(self):

        # Design Variables
        self.add_input('alpha', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('TE1', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('TE2', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('TE3', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('TE4', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('TE5', val=0.0)
        self.add_input('TE6', val=0.0)

        self.add_output('CD', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('CL', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('CY', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('CMx', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('CMy', val=0.0)
        self.add_output('CMz', val=0.0)

        self.input_file = 'designVar.in'
        self.output_file = 'fun3dResponse.out'
        self.derivs_file = 'fun3dDerivs.out'

        # providing these is optional; the component will verify that any input
        # files exist before execution and that the output files exist after.
        self.options['external_input_files'] = [self.input_file]
        self.options['external_output_files'] = [self.output_file, self.derivs_file]

        self.options['command'] = [
            # sys.executable, 'runFun3DsensPA_Euler.py',
            sys.executable, 'function.py',
            self.input_file, self.output_file, self.derivs_file]

        # this external code does provide derivatives
        self.declare_partials(of='*', wrt='*')

    def compute(self, inputs, outputs):

        alpha = inputs['alpha']
        TE1 = inputs['TE1']
        TE2 = inputs['TE2']
        TE3 = inputs['TE3']
        TE4 = inputs['TE4']
        TE5 = inputs['TE5']
        TE6 = inputs['TE6']

        # generate the input file for the paraboloid external code
        with open(self.input_file, 'w') as input_file:
            input_file.write('%.16f\n%.16f\n%.16f\n%.16f\n%.16f\n%.16f\n%.16f\n' % (alpha, TE1, TE2, TE3, TE4, TE5, TE6))

        # the parent compute function actually runs the external code
        super(FUN3DExternalCodeComp, self).compute(inputs, outputs)

        # parse the output file from the external code and set the value of f_xy
        with open(os.path.join(self.output_file), 'r') as output_file:

            outputs['CL'] = float(output_file.readline())
            outputs['CD'] = float(output_file.readline())
            outputs['CY'] = float(output_file.readline())
            outputs['CMx'] = float(output_file.readline())
            outputs['CMy'] = float(output_file.readline())
            outputs['CMz'] = float(output_file.readline())

            print('OUTPUTS', outputs)

    def compute_partials(self, inputs, partials):

        # parse the derivs file from the external code and set partials
        with open(os.path.join(self.derivs_file), 'r') as derivs_file:

            partials['CL', 'alpha'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CL', 'TE1'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CL', 'TE2'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CL', 'TE3'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CL', 'TE4'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CL', 'TE5'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CL', 'TE6'] = float(derivs_file.readline())

            partials['CD', 'alpha'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CD', 'TE1'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CD', 'TE2'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CD', 'TE3'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CD', 'TE4'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CD', 'TE5'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CD', 'TE6'] = float(derivs_file.readline())

            partials['CY', 'alpha'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CY', 'TE1'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CY', 'TE2'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CY', 'TE3'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CY', 'TE4'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CY', 'TE5'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CY', 'TE6'] = float(derivs_file.readline())

            # Rolling moment partials
            partials['CMx', 'alpha'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMx', 'TE1'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMx', 'TE2'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMx', 'TE3'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMx', 'TE4'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMx', 'TE5'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMx', 'TE6'] = float(derivs_file.readline())

            # Pitching moment partials
            partials['CMy', 'alpha'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMy', 'TE1'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMy', 'TE2'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMy', 'TE3'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMy', 'TE4'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMy', 'TE5'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMy', 'TE6'] = float(derivs_file.readline())

            # Yaw moment partials
            partials['CMz', 'alpha'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMz', 'TE1'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMz', 'TE2'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMz', 'TE3'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMz', 'TE4'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMz', 'TE5'] = float(derivs_file.readline())
            partials['CMz', 'TE6'] = float(derivs_file.readline())

            print('PARTIALS', partials)

# Initialize OpenMDAO Problem
prob = om.Problem()
model = prob.model

# create and connect inputs
model.add_subsystem('p', FUN3DExternalCodeComp())

# Add Design variables
prob.model.add_design_var('p.alpha', lower = 1.0, upper = 10)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.TE1',   lower = 1.0, upper = 10)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.TE2',   lower = 1.0, upper = 10)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.TE3',   lower = 1.0, upper = 10)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.TE4',   lower = 1.0, upper = 10)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.TE5',   lower = 1.0, upper = 10)
prob.model.add_design_var('p.TE6',   lower = 1.0, upper = 10)

# Lift constraint
prob.model.add_constraint('p.CL',  lower = 10, upper = 120)
prob.model.add_constraint('p.CY',  lower = 20, upper = 250)
prob.model.add_constraint('p.CMx', lower = 20, upper = 250)
prob.model.add_constraint('p.CMy', lower = 20, upper = 250)
prob.model.add_constraint('p.CMz', lower = 20, upper = 250)

# Minimize Drag
prob.model.add_objective('p.CD')

prob.driver = om.pyOptSparseDriver(optimizer='SLSQP')
prob.driver.options['print_results'] = True
prob.driver.options['debug_print'] = ['desvars','ln_cons','nl_cons','objs','totals']

# prob.driver = om.ScipyOptimizeDriver()
# prob.driver.options['optimizer'] = 'SLSQP'
# prob.driver.options['tol'] = 1e-5
# prob.driver.options['disp'] = True
# prob.driver.options['maxiter'] = 20 # Maximum number of solver iterations
# prob.driver.options['debug_print'] = ['desvars','ln_cons','nl_cons','objs','totals']

prob.driver.recording_options['record_objectives'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_constraints'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_desvars'] = True
prob.driver.recording_options['record_derivatives'] = True

recorder = om.SqliteRecorder('results.sql')
prob.driver.add_recorder(recorder)

prob.set_solver_print(level=0)

prob.setup()

# Set input values
prob.set_val('p.alpha', 3.0)
prob.set_val('p.TE1', 1.0)
prob.set_val('p.TE2', 2.0)
prob.set_val('p.TE3', 3.0)
prob.set_val('p.TE4', 4.0)
prob.set_val('p.TE5', 5.0)
prob.set_val('p.TE6', 6.0)

prob.run_driver()
```

```shell
Exception: '_auto_ivc.v0'
====================================================================== Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/deslicjp/Documents/Software/OpenMDAO/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py", line 593, in _gradfunc
    sens_dict = self._compute_totals(of=self._quantities,
  File "/Users/deslicjp/Documents/Software/OpenMDAO/openmdao/core/driver.py", line 849, in _compute_totals
    totals = total_jac.compute_totals()
  File "/Users/deslicjp/Documents/Software/OpenMDAO/openmdao/core/total_jac.py", line 1414, in compute_totals
    self._print_derivatives()
  File "/Users/deslicjp/Documents/Software/OpenMDAO/openmdao/core/total_jac.py", line 1629, in _print_derivatives
    pprint.pprint({(of, wrt): J[of][wrt]})
KeyError: '_auto_ivc.v0'
 ======================================================================
capi_return is NULL
Call-back cb_slgrad_in_slsqp__user__routines failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

UPDATE: 08-07-2020 15:32

Any insight is appreciated!

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Can you provide some more info? What are you seeing that leads you to the conclusion that the optimizer isn't using your derivatives? (I don't see any obvious problems with your code.)

Comment: When I looked at the recorded information, for many iterations the do not have populated derivative information.  Additionally, when I monitor the screen output, I am not seeing the print('PARTIALS', partials) statement for each iteration, leading me to believe that the compute_partials() is not being executed.

Comment: The partials only get computed and recorded when the optimizer asks for it. An optimizer could proceed along a generated gradient direction until it deemed that it needed to compute a new one.  I don't know if that is happening here though, as it looks like SLSQP always computes a new gradient after each new design point for the simple models I've tested so far.  You could verify for certain that you are computing a gradient every time the optimizer requests one by commenting out the print statements at thhe end of openmdao/drivers/scipyoptimizer.py -- ScipyOptimizeDriver:_gradfunc.

Comment: After uncommenting the print statements, _gradfunc is only being used sporadically and not for every iteration.  Could this be an issue with the scipy optimizer? My scipy version is 1.3.0.

Comment: It's possible, but I don't know. I am using 1.4.1.  One thing you could try is PyoptsparseDriver, which also has a different implementation of SLSQP. You would need to install and build pyoptsparse from mdolab: https://github.com/mdolab/pyoptsparse

Comment: To make it easier to debug, I made a dummy code that returns an objective, constraints, and the gradients.  Using this 'new' code which I edited, I get a different error with the pyoptsparse slsqp optimizer which I put in the above post.  It appears that the gradients are being named properly?

Comment: Hm, that looks like a bug in print_derivatives. The bug is related to a refactor that eliminated the need for the user to define IndepVarComps.  I will look into this.

Comment: I have a fix up for that debug printing bug. It will probably be on the openmdao repo's main branch in a couple of days, but you can merge it early from here: https://github.com/Kenneth-T-Moore/OpenMDAO/tree/ken2